# Drawing a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Hi I am trying to draw the following complex equation $$|z|^2+3z+3\bar{z}+10=0$$ I got the following $x^2+y^2+6x+10=0$ which is not possible to draw. I am wondering whether my calculation is wrong or the question has mistakes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your calculation seems correct. No solution.

Comment: Where did you found this?

Comment: @TheGeekGreek Someone asked me to do that and I answered that it has no solution. I was making sure of that

Comment: @mint Ah nice, you were right about this.

Comment: @Cardinal Yes I wanted to draw that equation. Since it has no solution, no way we can draw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by letting $z=x+iy$ we get,
$$|z|^2+3z+3\bar{z}+10=x^2+y^2+6x+10=(x+3)^2+y^2+1\geq 1>0.$$
So your equation does not have solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider $$x^2 + 6x + (10 + y^2) = 0$$ as a polynomial of $x$, then the discrimant is given by $$-(4 + y^2)< 0$$ and thus would imply $x \in \mathbb{C}$. Therefore, there exists no solution to this equation.